# Jenkins declarative pipeline : How to configure the klocwork result display on the job page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, klocwork

I am creating a pipeline using the declarative pipeline flavour, with clockwork steps enclosed within a klockwork wrapper where I can define the klocwork setup :

```
klocworkWrapper(installConfig: 'My Klocwork', ltoken: "${HOME}/.klocwork/ltoken", serverConfig: 'Klocwork@XYZ', serverProject: 'S3cr3TPr0j3ct') {
    klocworkBuildSpecGeneration([additionalOpts: '', buildCommand: 'make', ignoreErrors: true, output: 'kwinject.out', tool: 'kwinject'])
    klocworkIntegrationStep1([additionalOpts: '', buildSpec: 'kwinject.out', disableKwdeploy: false, ignoreCompileErrors: true, importConfig: '', incrementalAnalysis: false, tablesDir: 'kwtables'])
    klocworkIntegrationStep2([additionalOpts: '', buildName: "${JOB_BASE_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}", tablesDir: 'kwtables'])
}
```

Ok, analysis is launched, and I can see the results on the Klocwork server web interface.
But I cannot find a way to retrieve resulting diagrams on the Jenkins web interface, even when using the pipeline script generator.
Unless I am totally wrong, I think that I should use klocworkQualityGateway, but the generated script snippet is not correct.
Once copied within the wrapper, it fails lacking for some enableXYGateway or gatewayXYConfig property.

For example this line :

```
klocworkQualityGateway([enableCiGateway: false, enableServerGateway: true, gatewayServerConfigs: [[conditionName: 'Issues', jobResult: 'failure', query: 'state:+Status,Fix', threshold: '1']]])
```

fails with an error message :

```
WorkflowScript: 92: Missing required parameter: "gatewayCiConfig" @ line 92, column 1.
   klocworkQualityGateway([enableCiGateway: false, enableServerGateway: true, gatewayServerConfigs: [[conditionName: 'Issues', jobResult: 'failure', query: 'state:+Status,Fix', threshold: '1']]])
```

I really cannot find a way to make it work, and I guess I can take a wrong turn... so any help would be appreciate.

Thanks for your help and best regards
J-L

Comment: Well, after a fruitful discussion with the plugin maintainer (M. Baron) it appears that there is currently no simple and direct solution to display Klocwork result on a pipeline job page.
He said :

`This step doesn't have a native pipeline interface and a few people have tried, but haven't had much success with workarounds to use this in a pipeline.`

The simplest thing to do seems to trigger a freestyle job that will only do that.

As far as I have understood, a new plugin version with full pipeline support will replace the current one.

So, I think this discussion can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a fruitful discussion with the plugin maintainer (M. Baron) it appears that there is currently no simple and direct solution to display Klocwork result on a pipeline job page.
He said :

> This step doesn't have a native pipeline interface and a few people
>   have tried, but haven't had much success with workarounds to use this
>   in a pipeline.

The simplest thing to do seems to trigger a freestyle job that will only do that.

As far as I have understood, a new plugin version with full pipeline support will replace the current one.

So, I think this discussion can be closed.